# has_one vs. defining as a Key for Embedded documents for MongoMapper and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

The Source code is

```
class RealTimeDetail
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  key :url, String
  key :method, String
end

class TargetFeed
  include MongoMapper::Document  

  key :name, String, :null => false
  key :feed_type, String, :null => false 
  has_one :real_time_detail

end
```

When I do target_feed.real_time_detail = RealTimeDetail.new(:url => "http://example.com", :method => "get")

I get errored out.

Instead i've changed the TargetFeed to

```
class TargetFeed
  include MongoMapper::Document  

  key :name, String, :null => false
  key :feed_type, String, :null => false 
  key :real_time_detail, RealTimeDetail

end
```

This works but was wondering if this is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes no longer inherit from `ActiveRecord`, and `has_one` belongs to `ActiveRecord`, so it's not available for use. Using an explicit `key` seems like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

MongoMapper uses different syntax for implementing associations between data models. Details here: http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/associations.html

the short of it is, instead of `has_one`, use `one`

```
class TargetFeed
  include MongoMapper::Document  

  key :name, String, :null => false
  key :feed_type, String, :null => false 
  one :real_time_detail

end
```

I believe that since you've defined RealTimeDetail as an embedded document you don't need to declare an association in the definition of RealTimeDetail. If RealTimeDetail included Document (instead of EmbeddedDocument) you would use belongs_to from it's end:

```
class RealTimeDetail
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :url, String
  key :method, String
  belongs_to :target_feed
end
```